# Adding date and time in excel with added alphabets in between

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I need to add a date and time and the result should be in the following format with alphabet T in between and Z at the end. Is there any kind of formula that I can use here? Thanks. I have date and time in the following format 2016-10-03,  00:00:00. And the combined format i need is 2016-10-03T00:00:00Z

Comment: If your values are not strings, but real date-time values, simple use custom formatting and use "JJJJ-MM-DD\Thh:mm:ssZ" as type

Comment: I tried that. But I will be using VLOOKUP function on these combined date and time and they dont work in VLOOKUP.

Comment: So I need a formula to add both these with alphabets

Comment: So use Text([Cell],"JJJJ-MM-DD\Thh:mm:ssZ") to convert your values to a string and then vlookup on the result

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula,

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","T")&"Z"`